# How can i add a pause functionality in this timer ? React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, cs50

//Importing different files

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Button } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';
```

//Creating a stylesheet

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appContainer : {
    flex :1 ,
    alignItems : 'center',
    justifyContent : 'center',
  },
  text : {
    fontSize : 40 ,
  }
})

export class App extends React.Component{
```

//Creating a constructor function and setting state here

```
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props)
    this.state = ({
      minutes : 0,
      seconds : 4,
      pause : false,
  })
}
```

//Timer starting function for minutes and if it gets decreased by 1 then automatically set the seconds state.

```
startTimer = () => {
  this.setState({
     minutes : this.state.minutes - 1,
    seconds : 4
    })
 }
```

//Timer2 for decreasing seconds by 1 every instant.

```
 startTimer2 = () => {
  this.setState({
    seconds : this.state.seconds - 1 

  })
  console.log(this.props.toggle)

 }
```

//Setting interval for both timers here.

```
 componentDidMount = () => {
 this.interval = setInterval(this.startTimer , 5000)
   this.interval2 = setInterval(this.startTimer2 , 1000) 
 }
```

//Don't update if minutes gets below zero.

```
 shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps , nextState) => {
 if(nextState.minutes >= 0 ) 
 {
 return( 

true
 )
 }
```

// JUST clear INterval if it gets below

```
 else {
  clearInterval(this.interval)
  clearInterval(this.interval2)
   }
   }
```

//Component will get unmount

```
   componentWillUnmount = () => {
   clearInterval(this.interval)
   clearInterval(this.interval2)
   }
```

//Toggler for pausing the time

```
   pauseTimer = ()=> {
                  this.setState({
                      pause : !this.state.pause
                                               })
                                   }
```

//A render function

```
         render() {

                  if(this.state.minutes === 0  && this.state.seconds === 0)
 {
     return(
      <View style = {styles.appContainer}>
  <Text style ={styles.text}>
  Break is over
  </Text>

  </View>
    )

    }
     else if (this.state.pause === false)
     {

     return (
     <View style = {styles.appContainer}>
     <Text style ={styles.text}>
     {this.state.minutes} : {this.state.seconds}

      </Text>
      <Button title = "Pause" onPress = {()=>this.pauseTimer()} 
      />

      </View>
      )
      }

    else {

     return (
     <View style = {styles.appContainer}>
     <Text style ={styles.text}>
      {this.state.minutes} : {this.state.seconds}
                Paused
          </Text>
      <Button title = "Start again" onPress = {()=>this.pauseTimer()}/>
     </View>
         )

       }

      }
```

Comment: You can’t pause a `setInterval`. But you can stop it with `clearInterval` when someone presses the pause button. You don’t need two intervals for minutes and seconds. Just count the seconds and divide by 60.

Comment: And how to re start ?

Comment: You can use `setInterval` again to unpause the timer.

Comment: @Kokodoko Will try it and let you know.

Comment: Seems like i can't modify it , can you please show me how it can be implemented? I am very new to react native.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a short snippet in pure javascript, showing how to stop and restart an interval. It counts up by the second.

It also shows how you can calculate minutes and seconds with one counter.

Sorry, but I have not implemented this in React! You still have to implement this in your React template, but the `setInterval` logic and the seconds counter should work the same.

```
let id;
let paused = true;
let seconds = 0;
let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  toggleTimer();
});

function startTimer(){
  id = setInterval(()=>{
    seconds++;
    let minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
    let sec = seconds%60;
    console.log(minutes + " : " + sec);
  }, 1000);
}

function stopTimer(){
  clearInterval(id);
}

function toggleTimer(){
  console.log(paused);
  if(paused){
    paused = false;
    startTimer();
  } else {
    paused = true;
    stopTimer();
  }
}
```